Automatically determine all ctan packages necessary to compile
I keep a relatively lean texlive and install individual packages as necessary through tlmgr. Sometimes I begin to work with a colleague and have to compile a new paper.
Right now, my process is to attempt to compile (typically with pdflatex). If the compiler complains, for example, saying File 'cancel.sty' not found, then I'll install the necessary package through tlmgr. Then I try to compile again, and repeat as necessary.
Admittedly, this isn't the worst thing. It takes maybe 5 minutes to get up to speed on a new project. But it would be nice if there were a tool to determine all necessary or missing packages at once. I'm imagining a tool that collects all dependencies and writes something like a dependencies.txt that are common in python.
Does something like that exist?

I'll also note that I might be trying to optimize an incorrect solution to this problem. If I should be thinking about dependency management in a totally different way, then please let me know. But I have no plan on installing an enormous texlive for space reasons.

https://ctan.org/pkg/texliveonfly (no idea if this still works)

One can script something up to do a reasonable amount of the work in Lua. The script below works using TeX Live's --recorder data, so needs you do do something like
pdflatex <name> --recorder

before
texlua depreader.lua <name>

(assuming you call the script depreader.lua, which is what I have). There are then a few more restrictions

Only files read by a TeX run can be picked up; things needed by e.g. Biber or MakeIndex will be missed (picking these up would need some form of modified kpse I suspect, more akin to MiKTeX)
It is down to you to ensure that the recorder run has everything set up (e.g. conditional loading, multiple runs, etc. may cause issues)
It doesn't pick up files used in format building (hyphenation patterns, etc.)
It's quite slow as it needs to call tlmgr for every file name
It does not account for dependencies listed in the TeX Live database
(so every TL package is listed explicitly)

That said, I think it will get you moving:
local name = arg[1] or "test"

local execute = os.execute
local find = string.find
local gmatch = string.gmatch
local gsub = string.gsub
local insert = table.insert
local match = string.match
local popen = io.popen
local sort = table.sort

local function extract_name(file)
  local path, name = match(file,"^(.*)/([^/]*)$")
  if path then
    return name
  else
    return file
  end
end

local f = io.open(name .. ".fls")
local data = gsub(f:read("*all") .. "\n","\r\n","\n")

local t = {}

for line in gmatch(data,"([^\n]*)\n") do
  if not (line == ""
       or match(line,name .. ".tex$")
       or match(line,"^PWD ")
       or match(line,"^OUTPUT")
       or match(line,"^INPUT %./")
       or match(line,"%.aux$")
       or match(line,"%.cnf$")
       or match(line,"%.fmt$")
       or match(line,"texmf%-var")) then
    local file = extract_name(gsub(line,"^INPUT ",""))
    t[file] = line
  end
end

local pkgs = {}
local unmatched = {}

for name,path in pairs(t) do
  local f = popen("tlmgr search --file /" .. name)
  local data = f:read("*all")
  local _,n = gsub(data,":","")
  if n == 1 then
    pkgs[match(data,"^([^:]*)")] = true
  elseif n == 0 then
    unmatched[name] = true
  else
    local function search(data,path)
      local pkgline = ""
      for line in gmatch(data,"([^\n]*)\n") do
        if match(line,":$") then
          pkgline = line
        else
          -- Find 'plain' - no patterns, also trimming spaces
          if find(path,gsub(line,"%s+",""),0,true) then
            return gsub(pkgline,":$","")
          end
        end
      end
      return false
    end
    local pkg = search(data,path)
    if pkg then
      pkgs[pkg] = true
    else
      unmatched[name] = true
    end
  end
end

local function print_sorted(t)
  local s = {}
  for k,_ in pairs(t) do
    insert(s,k)
  end
  sort(s)
  for _,v in ipairs(s) do
    print(v)
  end
end

print("TeX Live packages")
print_sorted(pkgs)

if next(unmatched) then
  print("\nNo match for")
  print_sorted(unmatched)
end

If there is interest, I may try to make this a bit smoother, but not to the extent of trying to do what latexmk, etc., would do in terms of multiple runs, etc.

This is definitely in the spirit. I love it, in one of those "oh gosh this is terrible I love it" sort of ways. This is also the first time I've seen something useful with luatex. Excellent.

@davidlowryduda I'm only using Lua here as it's a convenient scripting language that's definitely available with any TeX installation :)
